# Ambiguous message in PersistenceException: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0

I'm facing my first "big project" and my data structure is quite complex, so I'm building my `@Entity` classes one by one and testing all my operation with a [TDD process](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Software_Engineering/Testing/Test-driven_Development). Also I'm using `hibernate-entitymanager` (which depends on `hibernate-core`) to generate an in-memory HSQLDB and to not depends on a *real DB connection*. But I'm getting the following error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: sigeaPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1134)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:793)
    ...
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at ar.edu.unt.sigea.commontest.RepositorioBaseTest.iniciarDBTest(RepositorioBaseTest.java:16)
```

The last one is my class. The thing is that the message `Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory` doesn't give me very much information to look where the error can be, because the exception is thrown when building the persistence context.

How can I get a clue of where the error can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you face that specific exception is useful the stack trace. In general, Hibernate throws exceptions with useful messages, but they are wrapped somewhere in the **method calling stack** (I don't know if that's the correct term, but I mean all the methods mentioned in the stack trace) and in the end you get a `PersistenceException` with that message.

So in those cases it's useful to check source code of the method in the bottom of the stack, in this case `org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1134)` (of course, you must has the sources at hand, it's a piece of cake with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) and the IDE of your preference, mine is [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org)). In this case, if you go to the corresponding line of the `CollectionBinder.java` you can see the following:

```
throw new AnnotationException(
    "Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: " + path + "[" + collType + "]");
```

So check the last `@OneToMany` and/or `@ManyToMany` annotation you made and how it's configured in the inverse side of the relationship (the entity class with the `@ManyToOne` or the `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = ...)` annotation). Here are good sources to check:

- [WikiBooks - Java Persistence/OneToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)
- [WikiBooks - Java Persistence/ManyToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany)
- [WikiBooks - Java Persistence/ManyToOne](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne)